# Google Place API & TOS for using on iOS6

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

Can you still use Google Places API to fetch places data for iOS Apps, now that Apple has removed Google Maps?

The Places API TOS clearly states that the data has to be displayed on Google Maps.  This cannot be done on iOS6, unless you take the user out of the App into a browser based Map.  The UX is going to suck.

Any responses from Google Places API team?

Thanks
AP

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same question and unfortunately, from what I understand of the TOS you won't be able to use the geocoding API as results need to be returned on a google map

the places API results CAN be used if you do not return results on a map and credit data source with google logos

https://developers.google.com/places/policies

again, that's my interpretation so hopefully someone will chip in and clarify

Apple's switch to their own maps is turning out to be a real pain in the arse